# Find the degree of the polynomial under several different conditions

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

[image]

I am doing part b. Are we supposed to have several different formulas for $H_p$ when $p$ has different values? And if that's the case, I've already solved it when $p=0$. And for $p=1$, $k$ can be either 0 or 1. And $H_p$ is of degree 3. So suppose $k=0$ and $H_p=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ but I'll only get 2 equations by substituting $x_0=1$ and $x_1=2$. I am not able to solve the equations since there are 4 variables. So any help? Thanks!

Comment: The equality must be verfied for both k 0 and 1

Comment: I chose to use Hermite interpolation and not sure if I was correct.

Comment: But for the final answer, I should have 3 different formulas for $p=0,1,2$. Is that correct?

Comment: The problem is asking for three polynomial approximations of the function. It never asked for Hermite polynomials.

Comment: I am using Hermite to find those three different polynomials.

Comment: The problem is asking for the polynomials that have values and first $p$ derivatives in $x_0$ and $x_1$ equal to the function.

Comment: Ok so what should I do to find the polynomials if not by using Hermite?

Comment: You got two equations for $H_1^{(0)}$, two other equations come with $H_1^{(1)}$. Solve the system and you'll have your polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

The problem asks you to find the polynomial for which: $$
H_p^{(k)}(x_j)=f^{(k)}(x_j)
$$
So, for $p=1$, $H_1(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3$, $H_1'(x)=c_1+2c_2x+3c_3x^2$:$$
H_1^{(0)}(x_0)=c_0=f(x_0)=1
$$ $$
H_1^{(0)}(x_1)=c_0+2c_1+4c_2+8c_3=f(x_1)=4
$$ $$
H_1^{(1)}(x_0)=c_1=f'(x_0)=\ln2
$$ $$
H_1^{(1)}(x_1)=c_1+4c_2+12c_3=f'(x_1)=4\ln2
$$
Solving the system you find the polynomial: $$
H_1(x)=1+\ln2\;x+\frac{1}{4}(9-12\ln2)x^2+\frac{1}{4}(5\ln2-3)x^3
$$
The same applies for $H_2$ where you have 2 derivatives to match.

Comment: got it! Thanks! My answer is different from yours and I guess I made mistakes somewhere. I'll check.

Comment: And any thoughts on part c? I don't know how to start.

Comment: As for the point c I rember something like that when I was at school, but now I don't remind. I think it is a consequence for Hermite polynomials, thought, so maybe you can find something in your books.

Comment: okay thanks!!!!